# mongodb aggregation project objectId with concat

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.test.aggregate({
    $match : { "themType" : "SuperTest" , "mType" : { "$in" : [ 1 , 2]}}
}, 
{ $project : { "_id" : 1, "refTestId" : 1, "avatar" : { $concat : [$refTestId] }
  } });
```

and avatar returns me null, probably its because its objectId, is it possible in this query to make from this objectId string ?

Comment: can you post a sample document from your collection?

Comment: I don't think we can help you fully if you can't fully state the problem. `$concat` is an operator for strings; it won't work with other types.

Answer (score 2):

From MongoDB 4.0 and newer, there is a [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/#exp._S_toString) operator which returns the `ObjectId` value as a hexadecimal string:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "themType": "SuperTest", 
        "mType": { "$in" : [1 , 2] }
    } },
    { "$addFields": { 
        "avatar": { "$toString": "$refTestId" }
    } }
])
```

or using [`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#convert-to-objectid)

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "themType": "SuperTest", 
        "mType": { "$in" : [1 , 2] }
    } },
    { "$addFields": { 
        "avatar": { 
            "$convert": { "input": "$refTestId", "to": "string" }
        }
    } }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible yet. WiP issue see: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29512