# Is it possible to $concat two DBRefs in a MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a collection of transactions with each document containing buyer and seller DBRefs:

```
{
    "buyer" : {
        "$ref" : "buyer",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5abbfd1926f6e66fd71c3e86")
    },
    "seller" : {
        "$ref" : "seller",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5abbfd1b26f6e66fd71c3fbe")
    },
    ...
}
```

I'm looking to perform an aggregation that will provide the unique number of buyers, sellers, and buyer + seller combinations. I can almost accomplish this with the following Mongo aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('transactions').aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group: {
          _id: null,
          buyers: {$addToSet: '$buyer'},
          sellers: {$addToSet: '$seller'},
          buyerSellers: {$addToSet: {$concat: ['$buyer.$id', '-', '$seller.$id']}}
    }},
    {
      $project: {
          countBuyer: {$size: '$buyers'},
          countSellers: {$size: '$sellers'},
          countBuyerSellers: {$size: '$buyerSellers'}
    }}
]
)
```

However, this presents me with the error: `FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.` I've tried other combinations like $user.id, $user._id, and $user.oid to no avail. I also can't concatenate DBRefs themselves so I'm wondering if there's a way to reference a DBRef's $id field in an expression?

Answer (score 0):

DBRefs can be problematic, and their usage is discouraged in the official MongoDB documentation. However, when you deal with DBRefs in an aggregator, you can still access their value using $objectToArray.

Try this :

```
db.getCollection('accessBucket').aggregate(
// Breakdown DBRefs into simple objects
// the format will look like this:
// [{"k" : "$ref","v" : "buyer"},{"k" : "$id","v" : ObjectId("5abbfd1926f6e66fd71c3e86")}]
// With $arrayElemAt, we keep only this part :
// {"k" : "$id","v" : ObjectId("5abbfd1926f6e66fd71c3e86")}
{
    $addFields: { 
        buyer_id: {$arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray: "$buyer"}, 1]},
        seller_id: {$arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray: "$seller"}, 1]},
}, 
// 
// Resume with your aggregator, Get the ObjectId value using $fieldname.v
// it should work just fine
{
  $group: {
      _id: null,
      buyers: {$addToSet: '$buyer'},
      sellers: {$addToSet: '$seller'},
      buyerSellers: {$addToSet: {$concat: ['$buyer_id.v', '-', '$seller_id.v']}}
}},
```

Comment: That does get me closer, but I receive an error letting me know that I can't use $concat on ObjectId's. That leads me to this question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107982/mongodb-aggregation-project-objectid-with-concat) and it seems that it may be possible in a newer version with a new $convert operator.

Comment: Maybe create a subdocument with two fields ?      
buyerSellers: {$addToSet: {buyer: '$buyer_id.v', seller: '$seller_id.v'}}